# Can I update an INT value + 1 and return the new value?

Tags: php, mysql, int

Is it possible in MySQL+PHP to increase an INT value and return the new value within one query?

```
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET number=number+1 WHERE id='uniqid'");

$updated_number = ???
```

Or I need to post another query?

```
SELECT number FROM table WHERE id='uniqid'
```

Comment: perhaps a stored procedure would help.

Comment: I think a stored procedure is in order, as an increment followed by a select carries the possibility that another increment may occur between the initial increment and the select.

Comment: Or if you are set on not using a stored procedure, selected the number first, then add one in php, then update, so that code can be sure it is using the number that it updated it to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simple answer - no, it's not possible.

Longer answer, yes, if you use a stored procedure that increments the value for the specified ID, retrieves the new value and returns it.

I've just tested this under MySQL 5.1.59:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE increment (IN uniqid VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
   UPDATE `table` SET number = number + 1 WHERE id = uniqid;
   SELECT number FROM `table` WHERE id = uniqid;
END
```

Usage:

```
CALL increment(uniqid)
```

If multiple simultaneous accesses are possible you may wish to `LOCK` the table first to ensure the operation's atomicity - MySQL apparently doesn't allow stored procedures to lock tables themselves.

Comment: why the new downvote?  AFAICS this does exactly what the OP wants!

Answer (score 7):

No. You will need to select that line afterwards

Answer (score 0):

There is way without procedure. You can store new value in session variable and get it from next statement.

UPDATE `table` SET number = (@next_value := number + 1) WHERE id = 'uniqid';

ant then:

SELECT @next_value;

Your session variable is not affected by other increments.

Answer (score -1):

you can do

```
status = mysql_query(mysql,
                     "UPDATE table SET number=number+1 WHERE id='uniqid';\
                      SELECT FROM table WHERE id='uniqid';\
                     ");
```

and use  `mysql_next_result()` to get the results.

Comment: This will not work. Multiple queries cannot be issued in a single query call. It is not allowed by the PHP mysql driver.

Answer (score -2):

@luvPlsQL is right. But basically you need to get the data first, next increase it and then update. At last you got the increased variable before update so you can use it.