# How to avoid a race condition when using a counter that is being read and incremented by two connections?

Tags: mysql, transactions, race-condition

For example, I have a "Connection1" wants to increase the "currentcount" counter, and then select the value. "Connection2" wants to do the same, and is running at the exact same time. These are the queries that are running (but not as a transaction).

```
Query 1: UPDATE table SET currentcount=currentcount+1;
Query 2: SELECT currentcount FROM table;
```

If Connection1 and Connection2 run Query1 at the same time, and then Query2 at the exact same time, then the result of query2 will be the same for both connections (i.e. a race condition).

I have heard that transactions may work in this situation.
How would I solve this problem in mysql?

Comment: Can you not use an auto increment and let the DB engine manage this for you?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8231775/6782

Comment: @gbn: Isn't autoincrement only used when inserting rows in a database table? I just want to update and read a single entry in the table.

Comment: @eric: yes, but then you can use LAST_INSERT_ID(). Do you really need a counter in a table?

Comment: @gbn `LAST_INSERT_ID()` doesn't avoid the race condition - you still have to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` followed by a `SELECT`.  It also _only_ works when you're adding new rows, not changing an existing row.

Comment: @Alnitak: I know, please don't state the obvious. Changing the process to use an INSERT is safer and more concurrent. Especially when tables can't be locked as per other answers.

Comment: @gbn it may not be obvious to other readers, and if the OP wanted to insert a new row each time he would have done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

```
LOCK `table`
...
UNLOCK `table`
```

Be aware that this can significantly affect concurrent performance as by necessity you have to prevent the second connection from doing *anything* at the same time as the first connection (and vice versa).   However this should only become an issue if you were performing this operation thousands of times per second.

Also, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8231775/6782) to a similar question where there's a stored procedure that can be trivially modified to make your increment / select cycle a single round trip to the server.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution that doesn't affect concurrent performance. I am running these queries up 10 times per second.

Comment: @eric 10 times per second shouldn't be a problem - this should only be an issue if you were doing it thousands of times per second.

Comment: If the query is actually an UPDATE with a WHERE rather than a single row table, then scalability will be limited